Why the BigQuery UI places an asterisk (*) next to the already saved query on run?
Every time I run a saved query from the BigQuery UI, an asterisk appears in its tab as if there was a change (nothing changed, both the code and the formatting are the same).
Why it happens and how to prevent it? The asterisk should only appear if a change was introduced.

Hi @a.s.t.r.o  I have posted an answer. I hope it will help you. do consider accepting and upvoting if it helps, as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research

Currently it’s not possible to prevent the asterisk( * ) .In the new Bigquery UI an asterisk is there when you select that query or run the query or currently active on that query .When you run many query at same time, so in all tabs it’s showing the  asterisk (*) mark.
So my personal opinion is after running a query save  it - like just press crtl s - then the asterisk (*) will vanish and then it’s not confusing and you can work on other query.
Before :

After press ctrl S 

